How to produce NFS errors on a linux machine? I want to get those logs when I run --> dmesg | grep -i 'nfs'
I'm trying to simulate NFS error logs. Tried few options such as mounting wrong shares with invalid IP/DNS name, but those did not produce any error logs. Is there any way to produce such logs? for example -
dmesg | grep -i 'nfs'
Typical messages might include:
    NFS: mount program didn't pass remote address!
    NFS: failed to contact remote server
    NFS: server <server> not responding, still trying
    NFS: server <server> OK

